# 2D array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to get this figured out. When I am putting in the code, I am getting an error from the `storyGrid = sr.nextInt();`

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DoubleArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(new
            File("C:\\Users\\Colton\\eclipseworkspace\\DoubleArray\\text.txt"));
        {
            int a = 6;
            int b = 7;

            int[][] storyGrid = new int[a][b];

            sr.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                    storyGrid = sr.nextInt();
                    System.out.print(storyGrid[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[][]

 at DoubleArray.main(DoubleArray.java:21)

Comment: Why did you use `storyGrid[i][j]` while *reading from* array cell at `System.out.print(storyGrid[i][j]);` but not while *writing to* array cell at `storyGrid = sr.nextInt();`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to index the array you are referencing to assign a value to an element in that array, example:

```java
int[][] storyGrid = new int[a][b];

sr.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        storyGrid[i][j] = sr.nextInt();
```

Also checkout the [java arrays tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error it's in your foor loop, your trying to assign the value of `sr.NextInt()` directly to an **Array type**, when I think you want to assign to the actual index of the Matrix so just change `storyGrid = sr.nextInt();` to:

```
storyGrid[i][j] = sr.nextInt();
```

I can suggest you to take a look to this [guide about arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm).